# Convert a matrix of positive integer numbers into a boolean matrix without loops

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

I'm trying to write code in Python using NumPy. I'm not sure it's possible but here's what I'm trying to do:

I have a 2D matrix `a` of shape `(rows, cols)` with positive integer numbers and I want to define a matrix `b` such that if a[i,j]=x then b[i,j+1]=b[i,j+2]=...=b[i,j+x]=1 (b is initialized to a matrix of zeros).

You can assume that for every j,x: j+x<=cols-1.

For example, if `a` is:

```
[0 2 0 0]
[0 2 0 0]
[3 0 0 0]
[2 0 1 0]
```

Then `b` should be:

```
[0 0 1 1]
[0 0 1 1]
[0 1 1 1]
[0 1 1 1]
```

Is it possible to do the above in Python with NumPy **without using loops**?

If it's not possible to do it without loops, is there an efficient way to do it? (`rows` and `cols` can be big numbers.)

Answer (score 1):

> If it's not possible to do it without loops, is there an efficient way to do it? (`rows` and `cols` can be big numbers.)

I'm sorry, I don't know a NumPy function which would help in your situation, but I think a regular loop and array indexing should be quite fast:

```py
import numpy as np

a = np.array([
    [0, 2, 0, 0],
    [0, 2, 0, 0],
    [3, 0, 0, 0],
    [2, 0, 1, 0],
])

b = np.zeros(a.shape)
for i, x in enumerate(a.flat):
    b.flat[i + 1 : i + 1 + x] = 1

print(b)
```

Which prints your expected result:

```
[[0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 0. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1.]
 [0. 1. 1. 1.]]
```

Comment: I upvoted, but because of flattening if e.g. `a[0,3]` is 1 then `b[1,0]` will become 1, which I think is not wanted.

Comment: @AndreasK. IIUC this is covered by "You can assume that for every j,x: j+x<=cols-1."

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slightly optimized solution of @finefoot

```
aa = a.ravel()
b = np.zeros_like(aa)
for i, x in enumerate(aa):
    if x != 0:
        b[i + 1 : i + 1 + x] = 1
b = b.reshape(a.shape)
```

And here's another solution which is slightly faster but less readable:

```
from itertools import chain

aa = a.ravel()
b = np.zeros_like(aa)
w = np.nonzero(aa)[0]
ranges = (range(s, e) for s, e in zip(w + 1, w + 1 + aa[w]))
for r in chain.from_iterable(ranges):
    b[r] = 1
b = b.reshape(a.shape)
```

Gives correct results under assumption that `j,x: j+x<=cols-1`. Both solutions use a for-loop though, but I don't think that it's possible to do it otherwise.